# Why didn't Palpatine account for the Jedi sensing his plans?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

Force Sense is to feel another being's feelings, impending danger and presence of the dark side, so technically Order 66 would never work.

In *Episode III*,

> Palpatine would hide again in the shadows. Padme wouldn't die, while giving birth to Luke and Leia, they would grow up together.

In *Episode IV*,

> Obi-wan wouldn't die,

In *Episode V*,

> Yoda wouldn't have to hide on Dagobah.

In *Episode VII*,

> Kylo Ren wouldn't been born as Han and Leia would never have met, and also Han Solo wouldn't die.

Also Episode 4, 5, 6, 7 wouldn't exist.

Comment: The dark side clouds everything.

Comment: He did, he clouded the Jedi senses with the Dark Side. That's why it took so long. Else he could have just given Order 66 just after the start of the clone wars.

Comment: @ewanm89 - Are you saying the war was causing the power of the dark side to grow so maybe their senses wouldn't have been clouded enough at the start? But even if he *could have* killed most of the Jedi from day one, I think he would have taken the time to get the Senate and the public increasingly trusting of his power, and increasingly sick of the war and increasingly inclined to see the Jedi as nothing but enthusiastic warriors as opposed to guardians of peace and justice. As powerful as he was, if the Republic army and public had seen him as a villain he probably couldn't have taken over.

Comment: Also, in support of the idea that Palpatine needed time to get the loyalty of the Senate, in Revenge of the Sith when Senator Organa is traveling with Obi-Wan and Yoda and gets a message that Chancellor Palpatine has requested a special session of congress, Organa suggests it might be a trap, but Obi-Wan says "No, I don't think so--the Chancellor will not be able to control the thousands of star systems without keeping the Senate intact."

Comment: I'm struggling to see what the question is here.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Yes, at the beginning of the war, the exact future was clouded by the end of the war all the Jedi senses were clouded. Yes you are right, it also allowed him to play the political games to the senate. But then again, he could have done it the way Hitler did and immediately execute those that were a problem and put people he did trust in their place to rule those systems, the long game is a better and more stable option though. I did state once the war started, that means he did already have the clones.

Answer (score 3):

### He did

Palpatine was able to use the power of the Dark Side to disrupt the foresight of the Jedi. From *Revenge of the Sith*:

> YODA:             Worse than war, I fear... Much          worse.
>
> PALPATINE:         What?
>
> MACE WINDU:            What do you sense, Master?
>
> YODA:          **Impossible to see ... The Dark Side           clouds everything.** But this I am          sure of—

Answer (score 0):

According to the Legends books Darth Plagueis, one of the techniques that Sidious was taught was to hide his presence, and to mask his force intents from the Jedi.  Also, Plagueis' master's master managed to create a rift in the force, allowing the dark side to flow more.  Years later, Plagues and Sidious meditated for several months on end which ended up shifting the force to tip more towards the dark side.  A combination of all of these allowed the dark side to cloud the Jedi and prevented them from seeing what was happening.